# Filtering a file

Tags: bash, file, unix, awk, filefilter

I have a file that contains many lines :

```html
at 12:00 the schedule is :

first_task:eating:fruit
second_task:rest:onehour
third_task:watching:horrorfilm  

at 18:00 the schedule is :

first_task:eating:vegetals
second_task:rest:threehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 22:00 the schedule is :

first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:sevenhours
third_task:watching:nothing
```

I tried to search before Asking . but I didn't find a way to filter the file the way I liked .

I would like to get a filtered file like this : 
for example If I would like to know what I am going to eat today .

```html
at 12:00  eating:fruit
at 18:00 eating:vegetals
at 22:00 eating:nothing
```

Is there any way to do this using awk or bash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`, you can do it as:

```
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /eating/{print "at "h":"m" eating:"$3}' filename
```

Output:

```
at 12:00 eating:fruit
at 18:00 eating:vegetals
at 22:00 eating:nothing
```

This will give correct answer, even if you have `eating` as second or third task.

Comment: thanks @Rakholiya Jenish but it gave me :     zsh: no matches found: [ :]

Comment: @Alexander are you using `bash` or `zsh`. Also can you give your `awk` version

Comment: The important thing was adding the quotes around the field separator `[\ :]`

Comment: @TomFenech thanks, actually I figured it out after writing comment that I missed the quotes around `[\ :]`

Comment: yeah I am working with zsh : I modified your command and it works perfectly . awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /eating/{print "at "h":"m" eating:"$3}' test.txt

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lne '$a=$1 if(/(^at\s+[^\s]*?)\s/);print $a." ".$1 if(/(eating:.*)$/)'
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/P2ogSF) for output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty simply with grep and sed. Assuming your example file is saved as `f.txt`:

```
egrep '^at|eating' f.txt | sed 's/first_task://' |
  sed  's/the schedule is ://' | paste -d' ' - - | column  -t
```

returns

```
at  12:00   eating:fruit
at  18:h00  eating:vegetals
at  22:h00  eating:nothing
```

Comment: the output :  eating:fruit     at  18:h00  
eating:vegetals  at  22:h00  
eating:nothing

Comment: not really sure if there are line breaks in your output, but you should have gotten what I posted (tested on OS X and Ubuntu). http://i.imgur.com/tnKi9oc.png is what I'm seeing.